# Why a new line character appending to shell variable?

Tags: ksh

I have used the method to assign the SQL output to a variable as below.

```
dbRole=$(${SQLPLUSPGM} -s / as sysdba <<-EOF
set head off
set verify off
set feedback off
select trim(translate(database_role,' ','_')) from v\$database;
exit;
EOF
)
```

But the variable o/p appending a `"\n"` character i.e `\nPHYSICAL_STANDBY`

However, when I use the below method it is working fine

```
${SQLPLUSPGM} -s / as sysdba <<-EOF | grep -v '^$' | read dbRole
set head off
set verify off
set feedback off
select trim(translate(database_role,' ','_')) from v\$database;
exit;
EOF
```

Any suggestion why it is appending `\n' and how we can get rid of it.

Appreciate your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Your second method, with the `grep -v`, removes the additional line.
You can use some filter inside your first method with additional parentheses.

```
dbRole=$((cat | grep -v "^$") <<-EOF
1
2
3

5

EOF
)
```

Alternative filters with some differences are `grep .`, `head -1`, `sed '$d'`.